# Происхождение частицы (междометия?) "ишь"

Tags: этимология, недопустимая-метка

Во-первых, никак не могу определиться с тем, чем, собственно, является "ишь". А во-вторых, интересно было бы узнать ее происхождение. Оно звукоподражательное или это сокращение от чего-то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Была чисто русская частица ВИШЬ, которая возникла из ВИДИШЬ в условиях быстрого темпа речи, как БИШЬ из БАЕШЬ,. Есть мнение, что ВИШЬ могло развиться и из ВИЖЬ-формы 2.л. ед.ч. повелит наклонения.В любом случае от глагола ВИДЕТЬ. Потом ВИШЬ устарело, осталось ИШЬ.

Может быть и частицей, и междометием:1. част., прост.   — Ишь ты, как бурлаки-то песни играют! В. В. Крестовский. Ишь как просто! Ишь ты как… Нет… я этому поверить не могу… Максим Горький, «Мещане»,

2.част., прост. употребляется при выражении неодобрения, осуждения, обиды ◆ Солдаты с завистью смотрели на проносившиеся мимо нас товарные вагоны, из открытых дверей которых выглядывали лошадиные морды. — Ишь ты, лошадям честь какая! А мы иди! В. М. Гаршин,

3.част., прост. употребляется при выражении несогласия с чем-либо, соответствуя по значению словам: вот ещё, ну да, как же, как бы не так ◆  — Дураки, — сказал Прохор, — в три шеи вас гнать… — Ишь ты, в три шеи! — сдерзил Филат.В. Я. Шишков, «Угрюм-река»

4.межд. прост. возглас, выражающий удивление, недоверие, сомнение  — То-то и есть что казенная, душенька. — Ишь ты! Словечко какое подобрал: душенька! А. И. Куприн, «Юнкера», 1932 г. — Прости, дяденька, — тоскливо сказал вор. — Про-ости-ить? Скажи на милость! Ишь ты! Как же так, сынок, я тебя могу простить? Ты, вор, украл у меня товару. Значит, следовает тебя упечь в тюрьму. Максим Горький, «Вор».